# アプリのiCloud対応について

Tags: xcode

既存のアプリ（AppID作成済み）をiCloudに対応させようとしています。
プロビジョニングポータルで作成済みAppIDを編集し、iCloudを有効化（Configurableという状態になっています）し、そのAppIDを用いて開発用のプロビジョニングプロファイルを新たに作成、XCodeへのダウンロードは済んでいると思われます。

XCodeで、Targetの設定（Capabilities）でiCloudをオンにしたのち、ServiceのiCloud Documentsのチェックを有効にするとエラーが出てしまいます。
ちなみに、Key-value-storageのみのチェックだとエラーは出ません。
[image: Capabilitiesの画面]

実機で起動しようとすると以下のようなエラーが出て起動できません。
[image: エラーメッセージ]

エラー解決のためのお知恵を貸して頂けると幸いです。
よろしくお願い致します。

【追記】
実機で起動できなかった件につきまして、プロビジョニングポータルでのAppIDの変更やプロビジョニングプロファイルの更新などのためか、XCodeのBuildSettingの設定が自動的に置き換わってしまっていたことが原因のようでした。Provisioning Profileの項目を設定し直したところ実機で起動はできました。
しかし依然iCloudについては質問時と変わらずエラーが出ています。

Answer (score 1):

既にご確認されていたら申し訳ありません。
Apple Developerサイトにて、App IDの設定とは別に、iCloud Containerの設定が必要になります。

https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/cloudContainer
こちらでiCloud Containerを作成後、App IDの編集画面でiCloud ContainerとApp IDを紐付けてください。

Comment: ご回答感謝いたします。iCloudContainerの設定は行っておらず、ご指摘の通りポータルにてコンテナを作成しAppIDを編集したらエラーが消えました。デフォルトのコンテナが自動的に作られるものだとばかり思い込んでおりました。